# Does this expression always vanish?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I have checked that the following expression

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1\\
j\ne i}^N\frac{A_iA_j(A_i+A_j)}{(A_i-A_j)^3}\prod_{k=1\\
k\ne i\\
k\ne j}^N\frac{A_i A_k}{(A_i-A_k)^2}
\end{align}
is zero for $N$ up to 7. I would like a general proof that it is zero for $N\in \mathbb Z_{+}$. I tried induction but I didn't find any inductive structure that I could make use of.

This was previously asked on math stack exchange ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770113/prove-that-the-expression-is-identically-zero ) and since there was no answer, it was suggested that I post the question here.

Comment: On MathOverflow, question titles that are commands (like "Prove that...") give the impression that the original source is a homework or textbook question. It's best to phrase the title as an actual _question_, not something that gives the impression you know the answer and you're challenging users here.

Comment: as a simple test, if I set $A_i=i$ for all $i$, the expression can be evaluated in closed form and gives 0.

Comment: Other observations: the expression can be written as $$(A_1\cdots A_n) \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \frac{A_i+A_j}{(A_i-A_j)^3} \biggl( A_i^{n-2} \prod_{\substack{1\le k\le N\\k\ne i\\k\ne j}}\frac1{(A_i-A_k)^2} - A_j^{n-2} \prod_{\substack{1\le k\le N\\k\ne i\\k\ne j}}\frac1{(A_j-A_k)^2} \biggr).$$This makes it easy to see that the order of the pole at any $A_i=A_j$ is at most $2$ (multiplying through by $(A_i-A_j)^3$ and setting $A_i=A_j$ yields $0$).

Comment: It seems equivalent to \begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1\\
j\ne i}^N\frac{A_i+A_j}{A_i-A_j}\prod_{k=1\\
k\ne i}^N\frac{A_i A_k}{(A_i-A_k)^2}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: There should be some symmetric function identity hiding here.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer but I am not entitled. By exchanging $i$ and $j$ one sees that each term in the double sum occurs twice, with alternating sign.

Comment: @quarta - no, it's not that simple. The product is not symmetric under exchange of $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Recall that
$$
  \sum_iA_i^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq i}\frac1{A_i-A_j}=1,
$$
as follows from the Lagrange interpolation of $x^{n-1}$.

Now apply $\prod_i \frac \partial{\partial A_i}$.
We get
$$
  \sum_i\left((n-1)A_i^{n-2}-2A_i^{n-1}\sum_{j\neq i}\frac1{A_i-A_j}\right) 
  \prod_{j\neq i}\frac1{(A_i-A_j)^2}\\
  = - \sum_i A_i^{n-2}\left(\sum_{j\neq i}\frac{A_i+A_j}{A_i-A_j}\right) 
  \prod_{j\neq i}\frac1{(A_i-A_j)^2}.
$$
Multiplying by $-\prod_iA_i$, we get what we need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Very nice answer and instructive approach. (+1) May I ask how you arrived at the expression with factor $n-1$? Is there a known formula, or is the expression tool based?

Comment: @epi163sqrt When dealing with the $i$th summand, you apply all $\partial/\partial x_j$ with $j\neq i$ first, that’s easy. Then it remains to apply $\partial/\partial x_i$, and, perhaps, it would be more clear if I wrote the result using the logarithmic derivative, as $\displaystyle \left(\frac{n-1}{A_i}-2\sum_{j\neq i}\frac1{A_i-A_j}\right) A_i^{n-1}
  \prod_{j\neq i}\frac1{(A_i-A_j)^2}$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I see. Many thanks for your reply and thank you very much for this elegant answer. I have taken the liberty of writing a slightly more detailed version of your response to *[MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770113/prove-that-the-expression-is-identically-zero/4777959#4777959)*.